# PostgreSQL - ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEDGES....SELECT ON TABLES... in all schemas

Tags: postgresql, permissions, sql-grant

Is it possible to alter default priviledges on PostgreSQL role, such that role has SELECT on any table in any schema (existing or created in future)

I have 3 roles (`app_r` is member of `app_rw` which is member of `app_rwc`)
and I am trying this:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE app_rwc GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMAS TO app_r;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE app_rwc GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO app_r;
```

but it does not work.

```
SELECT has_table_privilege('app_r', 'some_schema.some_table', 'SELECT')
-- false
```

Is there a way to do this in PG or do I have to use `IN SCHEMA` and repeat for *every* schema? (ughhh)

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE app_r IN SCHEMA some_schema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO app_r;
```

P.S.
I did try running ALTER DEFAULT *before* (and *after* also, just to test) creating schemas and tables...

P.P.S
My role setup is inspired by [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56725/70580) and I saw in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53936/70580) that is not necessary having to explicitly specify schemas

**UPDATE #1 -** Here is exact role setup I am using:

```
CREATE ROLE app_rwc INHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE;
CREATE ROLE app_rw INHERIT;
CREATE ROLE app_r  INHERIT;

GRANT app_r TO app_rw;
GRANT app_rw TO app_rwc;

-- these must be performed *before* any objects are created
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE app_rwc GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMAS TO app_r;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE app_rwc GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO app_r; 
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE app_rwc GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO app_rw;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE app_rwc REVOKE TRUNCATE ON TABLES TO app_rw;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE app_rwc GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON SEQUENCES TO app_rw;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to alter default priviledges on PostgreSQL role, such
>   that role has SELECT on any table in any schema (existing or created
>   in future)

As of version 9.6, no.

Comment: The docs mention "The privileges can be set globally (i.e., for all objects created in the current database), or just for objects created in specified schemas." My issue was that after creating a DB, you have to connect to it before setting default privileges.